# No servers available for service: while routing in Netflix ribbon

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

I had below working code in spring boot 2.3.4

```
public Route.AsyncBuilder apply(PredicateSpec route) {
    return route
            .path("/api/external/**")
            .filters(f -> f
                    .removeRequestHeader("Cookie")
                    .filter(loggingGatewayFilter)
                    .filter(oauth2GatewayFilter)
                    .filter(this::filter)
            )
            .uri("lb://external-url");
}
```

Config:

```
external-url:
 ribbon:
  listOfServers: "http://external01.com,http://external02.com"
  NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
```

When I upgrade the spring boot version to 2.4.2, code has to change to below.

```
public Buildable<Route> apply(PredicateSpec route) {
    return route
            .path("/api/external/**")
            .filters(f -> f
                    .removeRequestHeader("Cookie")
                    .filter(loggingGatewayFilter)
                    .filter(oauth2GatewayFilter)
                    .filter(this::filter)
            )
            .uri("lb://external-url");
}
```

since the netflix-ribbon has been removed in spring boot 2.4.2 I had to add those dependencies. In routing it gives below warning. Meaning the load balancer is not initializing.

```
o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer : No servers available for service: external-url
```

**How to resolve this issue**? **any alternative I could try to migrate this into spring load balancer**?

Dependency tree after upgrade:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.internetitem:logback-elasticsearch-appender:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] | \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] | | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] | | \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] | \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] | | \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.4.2:compile
[INFO] | | +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.4.2:compile
[INFO] | | \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] | \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.4.2:compile
[INFO] | \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] | | +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] | | +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] | | \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] | | \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] | | +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.58.Final:compile
[INFO] | | | +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.58.Final:compile
[INFO] | | | +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.58.Final:compile
[INFO] | | | +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.58.Final:compile
[INFO] | | | +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.58.Final:compile
[INFO] | | | \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.58.Final:compile
[INFO] | | +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.58.Final:compile
[INFO] | | +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.58.Final:compile
[INFO] | | | +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.58.Final:compile
[INFO] | | | \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.58.Final:compile
[INFO] | | +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.58.Final:compile
[INFO] | | | \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.58.Final:compile
[INFO] | | +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.58.Final:compile
[INFO] | | \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] | | \- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.58.Final:compile
[INFO] | | \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.58.Final:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] | \- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] | \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gateway-server:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] | | +- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] | | \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.1.7.Final:compile
[INFO] | | +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] | | +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] | | \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] | \- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] | | \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] | \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] | +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] | \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO] | +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.14:compile
[INFO] | \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.16:compile (optional)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-security:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] | +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] | \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] | | \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.4.2:compile
[INFO] | +- io.github.openfeign:feign-core:jar:10.10.1:compile
[INFO] | \- io.github.openfeign:feign-slf4j:jar:10.10.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] | \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] | +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] | \- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] | | \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-archaius:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] | | +- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.7.6:compile
[INFO] | | \- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] | +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] | | +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-transport:jar:2.3.0:runtime
[INFO] | | | +- io.reactivex:rxnetty-contexts:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] | | | \- io.reactivex:rxnetty-servo:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] | | +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.4.3:runtime
[INFO] | | +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:runtime
[INFO] | | \- io.reactivex:rxnetty:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] | +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] | | \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] | +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-httpclient:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] | | +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:runtime
[INFO] | | +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO] | | | \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO] | | | \- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:runtime
[INFO] | | +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-apache-client4:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO] | | +- com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.10.1:runtime
[INFO] | | | \- com.netflix.servo:servo-internal:jar:0.10.1:runtime
[INFO] | | \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-commons-util:jar:0.1.1:runtime
[INFO] | +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-loadbalancer:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] | | \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-statistics:jar:0.1.1:runtime
[INFO] | \- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-openfeign-core:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] | \- io.github.openfeign.form:feign-form-spring:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] | +- io.github.openfeign.form:feign-form:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] | \- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-loadbalancer:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] | \- com.stoyanr:evictor:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.4.2:test
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.4.2:test
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.2:test
[INFO] | +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] | | \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] | | \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] | | \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] | +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:test
[INFO] | | \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:test
[INFO] | +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.18.1:test
[INFO] | +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] | +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] | | +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] | | +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] | | \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] | +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.6.28:test
[INFO] | | +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] | | +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] | | \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] | +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.6.28:test
[INFO] | +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] | | \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] | +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] | | \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.3:test
[INFO] | \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] +- org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] | +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] | +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] | | +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] | | \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] | \- junit:junit:jar:4.13.1:test
[INFO] | \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-autoconfigure:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] | | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] | | \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] | \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-brave:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] | +- io.zipkin.brave:brave:jar:5.13.2:compile
[INFO] | +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-context-slf4j:jar:5.13.2:compile
[INFO] | +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-messaging:jar:5.13.2:compile
[INFO] | +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-rpc:jar:5.13.2:compile
[INFO] | +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-spring-rabbit:jar:5.13.2:compile
[INFO] | +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-kafka-clients:jar:5.13.2:compile
[INFO] | +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-kafka-streams:jar:5.13.2:compile
[INFO] | +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-httpclient:jar:5.13.2:compile
[INFO] | | \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-http:jar:5.13.2:compile
[INFO] | +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-httpasyncclient:jar:5.13.2:compile
[INFO] | +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-jms:jar:5.13.2:compile
[INFO] | +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-mongodb:jar:5.13.2:compile
[INFO] | +- io.zipkin.aws:brave-propagation-aws:jar:0.21.3:compile
[INFO] | \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-metrics-micrometer:jar:2.16.1:compile
[INFO] | \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.16.1:compile
[INFO] | \- io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:jar:2.23.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.6:compile
```

Answer (score 4):

The Ribbon config will not work with Spring Cloud LoadBalancer. For a static list of instances use [`SimpleDiscoveryClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#simplediscoveryclient) instead and pass your instances via properties like so:

```
spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances.service1[0].uri=http://s11:8080
```

If you want to have health-checks run against these instances, like with Ribbon, you should also set up [LoadBalancer health checks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#instance-health-check-for-loadbalancer).

Comment: Yeah I tried simple client. I wonder why there is no single liner to configure the url list.

Comment: Could you perhaps expand the answer to  include what is needed for the dynamic instances ( for ex consul ) ? Thank you.

Comment: For dynamic instances, you will just need to add the appropriate starters, for example, `spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery` and `spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer` and it will integrate out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue because spring cloud did not support zuul since 2020.
spring-cloud and netflix-zuul will work properly as following versions.

```
spring-boot-starter-parent: 2.1.3.RELEASE
java.version: 1.8
spring-cloud.version: Greenwich.RELEASE
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul: 2.1.0.RELEASE
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client: 2.1.0.RELEASE
jackson-dataformat-xml: 2.9.9
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server: 2.1.0.RELEASE
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer only if your routing is correct in your **application.yml or application.properties** files.

Here's what I did to resolve the issue **when everything including routing configuration looking correct to me**:

Step 1. Open your application's configuration file (usually **application.yml or application.properties**).

Step 2. Locate the Eureka client configuration section. It might look something like this:

```
 eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false
```

Step 3. **Change the enabled property to true or you can remove this property as default it is true:**

```
 eureka:
  client:
    enabled: true
```